# Difference between assignment by = sign and strcopy

Tags: c, mingw

The following code outputs "test". Shouldn't it print "te" only, since there are only two bytes allocated for x?

```
char *x = malloc(sizeof(char)*2);
x = "test";
printf("%s",x);
```

How does strcopy do this job correctly?

Comment: You aren't doing what you think you are.... You are reassigning x to point to a different constant string and leaking the memory you allocated.

Comment: That doesn't look like a duplicate, the OP here is assigning `x` a new value, not copying the content.

Comment: @JohnH would it still be the case if I use x= "te"; ?

Comment: Yes, it is a leak for the same reason.

Comment: @JohnH how can I let the allocated two bytes contain the characters "te" then?

Comment: Read the link that @user93353 posted.  It shows how to do that, and explains the consequences.

Comment: @user33856: `memcpy` or `strcpy`. Read a basic C tutorial… And if you changed your assignment to `strcpy(c, "test")`, you'd probably get the same result, but have undefined behavior. In C, you cannot determine if some code is valid by just compiling and running it…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, if you print the value of x before and after calling:

```
x = "test";
```

You will see that it has changed. By losing a track to your allocated memory, you face with memory leak here.

Furthermore, printf prints a string that starts from the pointer position until it finds the string terminated '\0' (0).

Suggested solution:

```
char* x = malloc(5);    /* sizeof(char) is always equal to 1 */
strcpy(x, "test");
```

Comment: Can you add in your answer how I can use the two bytes to contain the characters "te"?

Comment: You need at least three bytes to do it 't' 'e' '\0'

For dynamic allocation:

    char *x = malloc(sizeof(char)*3);
    strcpy(x, "te");